# How to convert div + useStyles to styled from @emotion/styled?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components, emotion

I am having trouble to convert material-ui makeStyles with theme which is applied to div into my custom div made with styled from emotion.

Following code is what am I trying to convert:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      '& > *': {
        margin: theme.spacing(2),
        width: theme.spacing(23),
        height: theme.spacing(23),
      },
      padding: '10px 10px',
    },
  }),
);
```

which is used in div like in this example:

```
<div className={classes.root}>someContent</div>
```

and my custom div made with styled looks like this, but the problem is that those options are not applied. (Side note: I am using the ThemeProvider from @material-ui/core/styles to supply the theme)

```
const CustomDiv = styled.div<{ theme: Theme }>`
  display: 'flex',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  '& > *': {
    margin: ${(props) => props.theme.spacing(2)},
    width: ${(props) => props.theme.spacing(23)},
    height: ${(props) => props.theme.spacing(23)},
  },
  padding: '10px 10px',
`;
```

Help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out (syntax used was wrong), my customDiv should be like this:

```
export const StyledDiv = styled.div<{ theme: Theme }>`
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  > * {
    margin: ${(props) => props.theme.spacing(2)}px;
    width: ${(props) => props.theme.spacing(23)}px;
    height: ${(props) => props.theme.spacing(23)}px;
  }
  padding: 2px 10px;
`;
```